# Maximum call stack exceeded error in React

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I saw it is already asked but it didn't help in my problem. I am using `componentDidUpdate` method to update my state. I am executing 5 patch calls, 5 get call to update my data. when I checked my network it is showing all the data call is executed properly except one call which was executing 3 times first 2 time with 301 status and last with 200, now I don't know why I am getting this error

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.overallMixData.map(data => {
      let filtereddata = this.props.VolumeGraph.filter(
        dataWorld => dataWorld.world_name === data.world_name
      );
      data.world_volume = filtereddata[0].world_volume;
    });
    this.setState({ minMaxgraphData: this.props.overallData });
  }
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    let newoverallData = prevProps.overallMixData;
    let Graph = prevProps.VolumeGraph;

    const newOverallData =overallData.map(data =>{
    let GraphData= Graph.filter(worldData => worldData.name === data.name);
      data.world_volume=worldGraphData[0].world_volume;
    })

      this.setState({ minMaxgraphData: newoverallData });

  }
```

this is my saga which executes the call

```
 try {
    const updateMixData = yield worldMixData.map(data => {
      return call(updateWorldMixDetail, data);
    });

    yield [put({ type: types.UPDATE_MIX_VALUES, updateWorldMixData })];
    const updateDetails = yield call(fetchData);
    const updateMixDetails = yield call(worldMixDetail);
     yield [put({ type: types.COM_DATAS, companyData:updateDetails })];
    yield [
      put({
        type: types.MIX_DETAILS,
        MixDetails: updateMixData 
      })
    ];

    const year = Math.max.apply(
      Math,
      updateMixDetails.map(function(data) {
        return data.year;
      })
    );
    const chnAggregData = yield call(channelAggregation, year);
    const volAggregateData = yield call(volAggregation, year);
    const MixAgg = yield call(MixAggregation, year);
    yield [
      put({
        type: types.FETCH_CHN_AGGREGATEDS,
        channelAggregationData: chnAggregData
      })
    ];
    yield [
      put({
        type: types.FETCH_VOL_AGGREGATEDS,
        volAggregationData: volAggregateData
      })
    ];
    yield [
      put({
        type: types.FETCH_MIX_AGGREGATEDS,
        MixAggregationData: MixAgg
      })
    ];
  } catch (error) {
    yield put({
      type: 'FETCH_MIX_UPDATE_ERROR',
      error
    });
  }
```

this is my console

```
 RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at MinMaxGraph.render (minMaxGraph.js:239)
    at ReactCompositeComponent.js:795
    at measureLifeCyclePerf (ReactCompositeComponent.js:75)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._renderValidatedComponentWithoutOwnerOrContext (ReactCompositeComponent.js:794)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._renderValidatedComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:821)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._updateRenderedComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:745)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._performComponentUpdate (ReactCompositeComponent.js:723)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.updateComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:644)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.receiveComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:546)
    at Object.receiveComponent (ReactReconciler.js:124)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._updateRenderedComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:753)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._performComponentUpdate (ReactCompositeComponent.js:723)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.updateComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:644)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performUpdateIfNecessary (ReactCompositeComponent.js:560)
    at Object.performUpdateIfNecessary (ReactReconciler.js:156)
    at runBatchedUpdates (ReactUpdates.js:150)
    at ReactReconcileTransaction.perform (Transaction.js:143)
    at ReactUpdatesFlushTransaction.perform (
```

Comment: I'm not sure but calling `this.setState({ minMaxgraphData: newoverallData });` inside `componentDidUpdate` would prob cause it to be called again and you will get a recursion here.

Comment: You need read about Lifecycle in react-native. `componentDidUpdate` is dispatched when view is rendered again, and the render is caused when you execute `setState`. Do you understand the infinite cycle you are causing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `setState` inside `componentDidUpdate` is fine. But you should know when to update and when not to. There are two arguments to `componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState)`. One should make use of the `prevState` or `prevProps` compare it with your `currentState` or `currentProps` and do your logic only if necessary.

So find out the condition when you should make the necessary `patch` and `get` calls and then set the state only if its needed. Calling it without any condition will lead to a loop since `setState` is updating the DOM again which in-turn calls the `componentDidUpdate`.

So your code might transform into something like this

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {

 const isChanged = [true/false]; // calcluate your condition based on props or state];

 // execute only if your condition is satisfied.
 if (isChanged) {
  let newoverallData = prevProps.overallMixData;
  let Graph = prevProps.VolumeGraph;

  const newOverallData =overallData.map(data =>{
  let GraphData= Graph.filter(worldData => worldData.name === data.name);
    data.world_volume=worldGraphData[0].world_volume;
  })

  this.setState({ minMaxgraphData: newoverallData });
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be very cautious when using a `setState` call inside a `componentDidUpdate` call, as this causes an infinite loop because `setState` triggers a `componentDidUpdate`.

If you need to update your state after you've received new props, try the [componentWillReceiveProps](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops) lifecycle method or make sure you add conditional logic to prevent subsequent updates.

Answer (score 0):

> you are using setState inside componentDidUpdate without using a break condition. 
>   thats why its  going in an infinite loop.